Why is body param on String's enumerateSubstrings(in:options:) marked as @escaping
The method in question is documented here. I don't think it is async. But, it being marked @escaping causes issues when I try to use it while implementing a similar method from NSTextSelectionDataSource. Since, my backing store is a Swift String, it seems like the easiest option is to convert the ranges from Swift string's enumerateSubstring's to NSTextRange and use it in the method from NSTextSelectionDataSource.
Example abstract implementation of my protocol method from NSTextSelectionDataSource.
func enumerateSubstrings(
    from location: any NSTextLocation,
    options: NSString.EnumerationOptions = [],
    using block: (String?, NSTextRange, NSTextRange?, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void
) {
   let string = // Get backing store string

   string.enumerateSubstrings(in:.., options: options) { substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, shouldStop in
     // Convert substringRange and enclosingRange
     let substringTextRange = ...
     let enclosingTextRange = ...
     block(substring, substringTextRange, enclosingTextRange, ...) // Compiler error here - Escaping closure captures non-escaping param block. 
   }
}

Why does Swift String.enumerateSubstrings need to escape it's body param? Is it safe to wrap block (from NSTextSelectionDataSource.enumerateSubstrings) within withoutActuallyEscaping

The implementation of String.enumerateSubstrings seems to be a wrapper around NSString.enumerateSubstrings which also is documented as having block as @escaping. But that leads to the same question. Why is NSString.enumerateSubstrings using an escaped block?
